# Android Dialog Box on submit

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a fragment which takes input from user
And it has 2 buttons
Submit and Cancel

when user enters the value and clicks submit
I want to have a dialog box that asks user does it want to save the values (should be a dialog box )and also the values should get stored and displayed (using shared preferences) next time the user runs the application.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

use android AlertDialogBuilder for this I am pasting this code from developer.android.com
May be this could help

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
// Add the buttons
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User clicked OK button
           }
       });
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User cancelled the dialog
           }
       });
// Set other dialog properties
...

// Create the AlertDialog
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

paste this into your activity inside your button listener or the method which is called when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple [android dialog popup library](https://github.com/00ec454/pop). It is very simple to use on your activity.

When submit button is clicked try following code after including above lib in your code

```
    void onSubmit(View view){ // your submit method.
             Pop.on(this)
                .with()
                .title(R.string.title)// you can skip if not needed
                .body(R.string.alert)// R.string.alert => "Are you want to submit your record? 
                .when(new Pop.Yah() { // positive button
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(DialogInterface dialog, View view) {
                        // save users preference to not show dialog again
                    }
                })
                .when(new Pop.Nah() { // negative button, you can skip if not neeed
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(DialogInterface dialog, View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Nah button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).show();
    }
```